# Codeigniter динамическое меню

Tags: меню, codeigniter

Здравствуйте! Недавно начал пользоваться `Codeigniter`, сразу же наткнулся на проблему. При загрузке отображения приходилось отдельно загружать `header`, основной вид(`template_v`) и `footer`. Потом переделал, сейчас из основного вида загружаю `header` и footer - с этим как то разобрался что бы каждый раз в контроллере не загружать их. А вот с меню не получается. Дело в том, что меню выводится из базы, а в виде если прописать `$this->load->view('menu_view', $menu)`, то пишет что `$menu` - неизвестная переменная. Сейчас так вот выглядит контроллер

```
$this->load->model('main_m');
$menu['menu_films'] = $this->menu_m->menu_films();
$menu['menu_serials'] = $this->menu_m->menu_serials();
$this->load->view('menu_v', $menu);
$data['data'] = $this->main_m->get_files();
$this->load->view('template_v', $data, $menu_view);
```

меню работает, но отображается по верх шапки сайта, так как в главном виде его не получается загрузить в нужном месте. Как тут поступить, что бы каждый раз не грузить это меню и вывести его в нужном месте или не как? Или может есть фреймворки по лучше CI? Я с него начал так как отличная документация и много нужных хелперов и библиотек.

Comment: @sew810i9, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: С сожалением вынуждены сообщить что CI скорее всего помрёт в ближайшее время (контора которая его разрабатывает, отказалась от дальнейшей  поддержки), лучше/хуже это холивар, фреймворков много, выбирайте на вкус и под задачи (если есть возможность попробуйте вообще не php)

Comment: что посоветуете в место php и чем кстати php вас не устраивает?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делаю так: в главном шаблоне сайта index.php проверяю, существует ли переменная $view, содержащая путь к файлу шаблона.

**Controller:**

```
private $data = array();
$this->data['view] = 'page/feedback';
$this->_tpl();

public function _tpl(){
 $this->load->view('index', $this->data);
}
```

**View (index.php)**

```
if (isset($view)) $this->load->view($view);
```

Comment: спасибо. Сделал не совсем так, но тем не менее работает.
public function index()
 { 
     $this->load->model('main_m');
     $data = array();
     $this->data['menu_films'] = $this->menu_m->menu_films();
     $this->data['menu_serials'] = $this->menu_m->menu_serials();
     $this->data['data'] = $this->main_m->get_files();
     $this->load->view('template_v', $this->data);
 }

Answer (score -1):

Как сказал eicto, codeigniter умирает. Поиграйтесь с ним немного, но если собираетесь писать что то сложнее блога, придется выбрать другой фреймворк.

Говорю по собственному опыту. Только в средине проекта на codeigniter я начал замечать что приходится писать слишком много костылей, кода становится очень много, а производительность падает.

В итоге я перешел на [fuelphp](http://fuelphp.com/). (форк codeigniter с 2010). После прочтения доков и просмотра примеров кода я просто не смог вернутся обратно к codeigniter.

Прошу прощенья, что ответ не по теме вопроса. Не могу комментировать.

Comment: благодарю за рекомендацию. Я как раз блог и не собираюсь писать, казалось бы в Codeigniter множество различных хелперов и готовых библиотек которые должны упростить жизнь разработчика, а тут выясняется обратное. Я конечно поспорить с вами не могу так как впервые работаю с фреймворком. Так что прислушаюсь к вашему совету и поищу замену CI. Просто не разу не видел столько готовых инструментов как в CI. В остальных все приходится самому писать, ту же авторизацию, пагинатор и т. д.